# Error 1001 during installation using installshield installer

Tags: installshield-2011

During installation I am getting error 1001 without any information about the error(just a dialog  is displayed). When click OK Button, rolling back occurs.
This happens in InstallShield installer.Can anyone help me whey this happens?